Correct way to add and subtract significant figures
There are actually two ways given to add or subtract significant figures in different books .In books like concepts of Physics by HC Verma it is written that round of the numbers given first and then add or subtract them but in others book it is written to add the numbers first and then round of the answer. Usually the answer is same but sometimes the answer is different for example while adding 24.36 + 0.0623 + 256.2 answer will come different both the times when we perform by both ways.
So what is the correct way to add or subtract significant figures?

The aim in numerical computing is to maintain as many bits of accuracy throughout the computation as you possibly can. FP arithmetic IRL can be fickle in ways that conventional mathematical algebra just doesn't see.
There is a better way numerically when summing a sequence of unknown data. Adding N random numbers together naively the worst case error is proportional to N so that rms error grows as ~sqrt(N). Much of this error can be avoided by a clever trick but with some loss of speed for the extra work done.
Kahan's compensated summation algorithm gets around that limitation by taking two bites at the cherry to add back some of the lost bits to the next summand.  There are more recent slightly better (ie more accurate) variants due to Neumaier and others but the original method was Kahan's.
Be warned it can be spoilt by overly aggressive optimisers so you might have to be careful with pragmas to make it work (and/or inspect the generated code).
GCC with -ffast-math doesn't get on with it at all see this Stack Overflow post.
The basis for this algorithm which dates back to 1965 is explained in much more detail at Theorem 8 in the excellent article "What every computer scientist should know about floating point" which I highly recommend. I'd say most scientists ought to read it and particularly physicists. The other related article is Fast2Sum.
Most scientific measurements are 6 sig figures or less so that another quick and dirty option is to sum them into a double precision variable which will hide a multitude of sins (even when computing a dot product).
Another option if you care about rounding and have them in an array is to sort the numbers into ascending order by their magnitude and sum from smallest to largest. This happens naturally in many special function polynomials where high order terms have something like n! in the denominator and a fixed range of |x| <= 1.

It is traditional to accept the answer and/or upvote it if you think that it is correct. This will help other people to find it when they ask similar questions in the future. Not enough people today are aware of Fast2sum and  Kahan's other impressive and varied contributions to FP arithmetic and numerical analysis.
